# Global variable not affecting values.yaml file in helm chart of Kubernetes (passing secretName and Domain Name from CLI)

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, openshift, devops, kubernetes-helm

I need one help over here. I am stuck while implementing helm chart.
Scenario: I need to pass value via CLI to `values.yaml` file. Below is the sample code.

values.yaml

```
# Default values for miqp-ui-dep.
# This is a YAML-formatted file.
# Declare variables to be passed into your templates.
##################Names of files and Applications################
Depname: miqp-server-dep
Appname: miqp-server
Svcname: miqp-server-svc
Ingname: miqp-ing
#################################################################
replicaCount: 2
strategy:
  type: RollingUpdate
  rollingUpdate:
     maxSurge: 1
     maxUnavailable: 1
minReadySeconds: 5
nodeSelector:
       role: nginxplus
image:
  repository: xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/miqp-devops
  tag: miqpserver_2sep
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
service:
  name: miqp-ui-svc
  externalPort: 80
  internalPort: 8081
volumeMounts:
  name: ebs-pvc
ingress:
  enabled: true
  hosts:
    - kubernetes-miq.xxxxxx.com
  tls:
    - secretName: default-token-k33w6
      hosts:
        - kubernetes-xxxxxx.com
persistence:
  enabled: true
  volume:
    accessModes: ReadWriteOnce
    pvcName: ebs-pvc
    storageClass: standard
    storageSize: 20G
```

ingress.yaml

```
{{- if .Values.ingress.enabled -}}
{{- $serviceName := .Values.service.name -}}
{{- $servicePort := .Values.service.externalPort -}}
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.Ingname }}
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
spec:
  rules:
    {{- range $host := .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    - host: {{ $host }}
      http:
        paths:
          - path:
            backend:
              serviceName: {{ $serviceName }}
              servicePort: {{ $servicePort }}
          - path: /api/
            backend:
              serviceName: {{ $serviceName }}
              servicePort: {{ $servicePort }}
     {{- end -}}
  {{- if .Values.ingress.tls}}
  tls:
{{ toYaml .Values.ingress.tls | indent 4 }}
  {{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

Now I can set the values of the parameter of values.yml using `--set` option, but what if we have to replace the parameter if it's in below manner?

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  hosts:
    - kubernetes-miq.xxxxxx.com
  tls:
    - secretName: default-token-k33w6
      hosts:
        - kubernetes-miq.xxxxxx.com
```

I have to replace the value of - secretName value i.e default-token-k33w6 and hosts i.e kubernetes-miq.xxxxxx.com

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can always do something like `helm upgrade --reuse-values --set ingress.enabled=false`, for a more complex one you can do `helm upgrade --reuse-values -f <filename>` where your file under  contains something like your example :

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  hosts:
  - kubernetes-miq.xxxxxx.com
```

as for running more complex structures via `--set` take a look at https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/master/docs/using_helm.md#the-format-and-limitations-of---set which refers to ways like :

```
--set key={a,b,c}
```

or

```
--set name.key1=a,name.key2=b
```

Comment: thanks for your input, but my question is, for normal values, I can simply put `--set image.repository=helloworld` , but in case of ingress, if you can see it's not in normal manner, it has `-` like  `hosts:` - `kubernetes-miq.xxxxx.com`

Comment: I guess it will use something like `--set ingress.hosts[0]=kubernetes-jahjhs.asdas.com`   but its not working

Comment: oh, you mean how to `--set` an array of values ? answer edited for that.

Comment: yeahh kind off. cause I am trying and its not happening :(

Comment: So we will leave that hosts and secretName value blank and pass it via CLI, we are doing this for automation purpose :)

Comment: I am trying to give `--set ingress.tls[0].secretName=default-token-xyzxyz` but still it is not overriding the last values.

Comment: Is this array functionality available in helm 2.3.0, cause I am using that.

Comment: 2.3 is kind of ancient in terms of helm lifespan so I strongly suggest an upgrade :)

Comment: Yeah I saw, array indexing supports after 2.5. Thanks for the help :)